# Custom link in return function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script/function in my WooCommerce.
This function changes the name of the button depending on the category and whether the user is logged in.

```
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

if ( has_term( 'kategoria', 'product_cat' ) ) {
  if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    return ( 'Download' );
  }
  else {
      return ( 'Log In to Download' );
  }
} else {
return __( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' );
}
}
```

Everything is ok but how to do that also when you click on the button to redirect an individual url?

Eg. The LOG IN TO DOWNLOAD button is redirected to www.example.com.

Comment: Your function can return the all html element not only the text like `return '<a href="blabla.php"> blabla </a>'` or button so this way you will have a dynamic html element which has a different url and text.